# PostgreSQL : Is this because of locks(row level)?

Tags: database, postgresql, geospatial, postgis, postgresql-9.1

I have a table with approximately 2.1 million tuples. Which has latitude and longitude columns. I am trying to convert this into a geographic type (point with SRID).

The function(procedure) I have written, works fine when I limit the entries (say : `SELECT id,longitude,latitude FROM list_of_location limit 50`).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION convertlatlon() RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN SELECT id,longitude,latitude FROM list_of_location
    LOOP
    UPDATE list_of_location SET location= concat('SRID=4326;POINT(',rec.longitude,' ',rec.latitude,')') WHERE id=rec.id;    
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;
```

---

- When I try to run it on the entire table, PostgreSQL seems to do nothing. Have waited for an hour and a half.
- Consumes 99% of CPU on the core it is running.
- Does not spring any other instance of PostgreSQL to utilize other cores(since the request is from a single user?).
- Is this because of locks(row level)?
- How to circumvent this?

*P.S. I am pretty sure this will get closed as off topic. But, I have to look for answers.*

Comment: "I am pretty sure this will get closed as off topic." Why?

Comment: @MarkByers Because this is not a programming related question. something like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712318/problems-starting-postgresql-server-after-installing-9-1

Comment: Why is this one not programming related? It *seems* to be to me - you have even posted some program code, so I can't see why it shouldn't be programming related. Am I missing something? Anyway if you still feel it's not programming related, you could try posting it in [dba.se](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @MarkByers I am confused with what is programming related right now(WRT stack overflow) because I have seen many questions, which seems to be programming related but gets closed as _off topic_.

Comment: "I have seen many questions, which seems to be programming related but gets closed as off topic." - Hmmm... I haven't seen that. If you are unsure why a question is closed as off-topic you can ask on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions).

Comment: @MarkByers thanks for the tip will do it from next time :)..

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. If you wanted to encode the (x,y) coordinates into a geometry, you could use something like `SET location = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(rt.xcoord, rt.ycoord), 4326)` in a plain sql update query. Concatenating them into a string makes no sense to me. (disclaimer: I am not a GIS expert).

Comment: @wildplasser It was very moronic of me for not thinking of the single statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what would cause it, but it sounds like there may be locks acquired in this operation. You can verify this easily though:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_locks;
```

will tell you what locks are currently taken. And

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activities WHERE waiting;
```

will tell you, if there are locks, which transactions are sitting there idle waiting for a lock to be released. That should point you on the right direction.

> Does not spring any other instance of PostgreSQL to utilize other cores(since the request is from a single user?).

This is how postgres works. A single session will spin off one backend. A single query does not do any sort multi-process or concurrent operation.

> How to circumvent this?

Why are you looping? I think you can do this in one shot. Why not do:

```
UPDATE list_of_location 
SET location = ST_GeogFromText('POINT(' || longitude || ' ' || latitude || ')');
```

(assuming that gives you the correct result)

Comment: +1 for mentioning that this can be done in a single statement.

Comment: very moronic of me for not thinking of the single statement. Thanks for info on locks :).

Comment: right on. Yeah, think in "Sets of data" when dealing with SQL, should make your life easier. For the most part.